# Change some contents of an existing file without deleting the other contents in the file in node js

Tags: regex, angularjs, node.js, fs

My aim is to change the color of the

```
.made-easy-theme{
            color:black
        }
```

in a css file with another color. but when I change the color using fs.writeFile it erase all the other content in the css file and replace only the

```
.made-easy-theme{
            color:black
        }
```

Before changing the color the css file includes below content,

```
@charset "utf-8";
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);
        @import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);
        /* entypo */
        [class*="entypo-"]:before {
          font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
        }
        .made-easy-theme{
            color:black
        }

        * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .toggler {
          color: #A1A1A4;
          font-size: 1.25em;
          margin-left: 8px;
          text-align: center;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        .toggler.active {
          color: #000;
        }

        .cardss {
          list-style: none;
          padding-right: 10px;
          padding-left: 10px;
          text-align: left;
          -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
          max-width: 100%;
          -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        }
```

but after changing the color it includes only,

```
.made-easy-theme{color:hsl(0, 22%, 51%)}
```

hsl(0, 22%, 51%)(color which I recieve from the client side).
My js file which includes the code to change the css file is below,

```
var main = 'temp/' + userId + '/templates/' + appId + '/css/main.css';
 var color = req.body.color;
function replaceThemecolor(color) {

        fs.readFile(main, 'utf-8',
            function (err, data) {
                var searchStr = ".made-easy-theme{color:black}";

                    console.log(searchStr);

                    var result = searchStr.replace(new RegExp('black', ''), color);
                    fs.writeFile(main, result, 'utf-8', function (err) {
                        console.log("kk");
                        console.log(color);
                        console.log(result);
                        if (err) return console.log(err);
                    });
            });

    }
```

I think the fault is with fs.writeFile method. I don't know how to get the right output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your current code:

1. You are reading the file contents, but not doing anything with it.  You're just doing a replace on a static string, so the original file contents it ignored.
2. Your regex is looking only for the black color which would match that anywhere in the file and would not match it after you had changed it.

I think you want something like this that makes a regex to match just the color in that rule.  You can make the regex as complicated as needed.  What I've shown here is flexible enough to support other styles in the `.made-easy-theme` rule.  It will pick out only the `color` rule to change.  It assumes the color is specified by name such as "black".

```
var main = 'temp/' + userId + '/templates/' + appId + '/css/main.css';
var color = req.body.color;

function replaceThemecolor(color) {
    fs.readFile(main, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
        var regex = /(\.made-easy-theme\s*{[^}]*color\s*:\s*)([^\n;}]+)([\s*;}])/;
        var result = data.replace(regex, "$1" + color + "$3");
        console.log(result);
        console.log(color);
        fs.writeFile(main, result, 'utf-8', function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Here's a working demo on a block of text without the actual file operations: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/e6923rqe/

Comment: I have done this and was working but some conflicts occurs. When try to replace the color twice it won't overwrite, the result is like .made-easy-theme{
            color:hsl(0, 44%, 45%)(0, 26%, 55%);
        } and when I try to replace other variables like font-family, it won't work at all

Comment: @adithya - it says right in my answer that this solution works only for colors specified by a name such a "black".  You didn't ask for more than that.  The regex would have to be changed if you want `hsl(...)` colors or `rgb(...)` colors to work.  With the right regex, it will work for font-family too.  If you can promise that the color value is terminated with a `;`, then it's a lot easier to make the regex.

Comment: can you at least give me a link that helps me to change my regex according to my requirements

Comment: @adithya - I don't know what your requirements are.  Your question does not specify them.  I made it work with the example you showed.  It's easy if you can guarantee that the color always has a semi-colon after it.  Not as easy if that is not the case because there are multiple different formats for color values which is not as easy for a regex.  You can find lots of websites that document regex syntax, but it requires learning how to use it to modify.  I'm not sure what kind of link you want.

Comment: I want to  replace the color when ever user change it and though I change the color attribute to font-size in the answer you gave it won't work for font-size

Comment: @adithya - I updated my answer so it will now work with the `hsl(...)` color format.  If you're looking for a generic solution that can be used for any CSS attribute name, then I'd suggest you ask a new question about that as that is a bit more complicated.  StackOverflow does not expect you to keep adding more and more requirements to the original question.  Once the original question has been answered, you can ask additional questions if you have new requirements you want to add on.

Comment: Thank you very much, it give the solution for my first problem

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this line:

```
var result = searchStr.replace(new RegExp('black', ''), color);
```

It is narrowing the scope of the `result` variable to only have the replacement of pattern **within** `searchStr` which initially is declared as:

```
var searchStr = ".made-easy-theme{color:black}";
```

So in `fs.writeFile`, `result` is then written to the file.